# EF List To Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list, datatable, group-by

I have a table named UserRoles and a user can have multiple Roles.My structure is;

```
 public class UserRole
    {
        [Key, Column("ID")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public User User { get; set; }

        [Column("USERID")]
        public long UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
        public Role Role { get; set; }

        [Column("ROLEID")]
        public long RoleId { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to display them in a grid grouped by userID.Do i need a new data structure?
PS: I am getting data in `List<UserRoles>` format.

Comment: You should add more information in your question. For example, that you want the roles separated by comma's in the second column of your grid. Expect to get incomplete answers if you provide incomplete questions. So don't only provide more info in comments to answers, but also update your answer.

Comment: I don't understand why people upvote such an unclear question that's also void of any evident research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.UserRoles.Include("User").Include("Role").OrderBy(ur => ur.UserId).ToList();
```

If you don't need to show User or Role details just remove Include.

**EDIT**

```
db.Users.Include("UserRoles.Role").Select(u => new { u.UserId, Roles = string.Join(",", u.UserRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role.RoleId)) }).ToList();
```

Entity User should have navigation property UserRoles:

```
public virtual List<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

Comment: No this is not i want. I want to list  1 user id and in the next column roles seperated by comma.
userId1---> role1,role2,role3